# In Whitehead & Russell's PM, what makes anything true or false?

Tags: logic, math-history, foundations

It seems that truth and falsehood are fundamental to meanings and types. A proposition is defined as anything that is true or that is false.

PM *defines* truth as "consisting in the fact that there is a complex corresponding to the discursive thought which is the judgement."* If I'm not mistaken, truth is not one of PM's primitive ideas. In Chapter IV of 1st ed introduction, the reason for pronouncing "$\{(x).\phi(x)\}$ is a man" as meaningless appears rather arbitrary.

I wonder if W&R assumed that the notion of truth is well-known. If so, whose definition were they referring to?

*Chapter II.Tuth and Falsehood.

Comment: I can't comment expertly on PM, but it is a theorem due to Tarski that truth cannot be defined within a formal system implementing arithmetic in a way corresponding to truth in the standard model of arithmetic. This is why modern logic concerns itself more with provability.

Comment: I think you might do better to ask this question on http://philosophy.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point of view of "logical machinery", we can say that *PM* assumes "true" and "false" as two undefined concepts that we are able to manage in the context of logic and mathematics.

See the definition of *truth-values*, page 8 :

> The "truth-value" of a proposition is *truth* if it is true and *falsehood* if it is false.

In pages 45-on, there is an attempt to define the concepts : *truth* and *falsehood*.

The context, as you already noted, is the "act of judgement", involving a mind and several interconnected objects. *True* is a "property" of the judgement :

> When the judgement is *true*, [...] there is a corresponding complex of the *objects* of the judgement alone. Falsehood, [...] consists in the absence of a corresponding complex composed of the objects alone.

This seems an enunciation of [The Correspondence Theory of Truth](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-correspondence/)  :

> Narrowly speaking, the correspondence theory of truth is the view that truth is correspondence to a fact — a view that was advocated by Russell and Moore early in the 20th century.
>
> The correspondence theory is often traced back to Aristotle's well-known definition of truth (*Metaphysics* 1011b25):
>
> > “To say of what is that it is not, or of what is not that it is, is false, while to say of what is that it is, and of what is not that it is not, is true”
>
> but virtually identical formulations can be found in Plato (*Cratylus* 385b2, *Sophist* 263b). It is noteworthy that this definition does not highlight the basic correspondence intuition. Although it does allude to a relation (saying something of something) to reality (what is), the relation is not made very explicit, and there is no specification of what on the part of reality is responsible for the truth of a saying.
>
> Aristotle sounds much more like a genuine correspondence theorist in the *Categories* (12b11, 14b14), where he talks of “underlying things” that make statements true and implies that these “things” (*pragmata*) are logically structured situations or facts (viz., his sitting, his not sitting). Most influential is his claim in *De Interpretatione* (16a3) that thoughts are “likenessess” (*homoiosis*) of things. Although he nowhere defines truth in terms of a thought's likeness to a thing or fact, it is clear that such a definition would fit well into his overall philosophy of mind.

Apart from all metaphysical implications regarding *objects* (what they are ?) and their "interconnections" into *complex* (what are relations ?), this basic account - as noted in Kevin's comment above - can be compared to well-known [Tarski's Truth Definition](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tarski-truth/).

Comment: I agree that mathematics can manage without a precise definition of truth and falsehood because it deals with implications, not empirical evidence for the truth of a proposition.

Comment: Still, I think it's hard to sum up a generic rule that decides what makes a proposition meaningless. Maybe, we can imitate empirical science and decide such matters case by case.

Comment: Correspondence theory is a sound criterion. Yet there are sentences which, at first sight appear to be meaningless, turn out to be capable of being true or false after clever analysis. E.g., "the so-and-so" ...